# How to access a member in struct as a double array and an address of a member in struct as an array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

New to understanding structs, especially involved with accessing a struct member's address or value.

I'm not sure about my use of language here, but I have:

1. a 2x2 matrix of struct a
2. struct x is an array of size 2
3. struct b of size 2 holds the answers

So far I have...

```
&(*(b+i))->s = (*(*(a+i)+j)).s * (*(x+k)).s
```

however I receive the compiler error

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

EDIT:

My struct

```
typedef struct num{
      int s;
}num_t;
```

My function parameters

```
 void calc(int n, int m, num_t **a, num_t *x, num_t *b)
```

Also, is the question phrased correctly?

EDIT2: Format

Comment: Need more information.  How are `a` and `b` defined?  How is your array of `struct`s defined?

Comment: This is all totally wrong. One should never ever write expressions like that. I suspect you want something like `b[i].s = a[i][j].s * x[k].s`.

Comment: why downvote? For a first question in SO, this is not bad. This shows some effort before posting the question. Downvoting such questions will drive new people away

Comment: @arunmoezhi the downvote was before the edit, which did not provide enough information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, the issue has to do with operator precedence. As written, the left operand of the assignment is equivalent to:

```
&((*(b + i))->s)
```

In other words, you're trying to assign a value to the address of a variable, because the `->` (pointer to member) operator has a higher precedence than `&` (address of) operator. What you want instead is

```
(&(*(b + i)))->s
```

However, this is grossly unnecessary, as the `->` operator expands to the `*` dereference operator and `.` member operator, so you get

```
(*(&(*(b + i)))).s
```

The outer `*` dereference and `&` reference operators, in this instance, effectively "cancel" each other out. So, you can rewrite it as just

```
(*(b + i)).s
```

Finally (and this rule can be applied to the other two pointer expressions), this is basically accessing an array element, so it's much clearer to write this as

```
b[i].s
```

So, your final statement should look like this

```
b[i].s = a[i][j].s * x[k].s;
```

This is much cleaner, and much more effectively conveys the intent of the statement, which is always important in programming.